# Why does td width get ignored and instead become 100%?

Tags: html, html-table

Ok, this is making me absolutely furious. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code, but for some reason, renders the 1st td out at 100% of the available width of the table, and the remaining td's just push and expand the width of the table. Anyone? If you want to see the full thing, check here. It's driving me f...ing crazy. [this is what happens](http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/eg.html)

```
    <!-- FOOTER -->
<tr width="630" align="left" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">

<!-- TEASERS -->
<td width="137" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">
<img src="http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/images/em-ft-tease-1.png" width="137" height="65"/>
</td>

<td width="125" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">
<img src="http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/images/em-ft-tease-2.png" width="125" height="65"/>
</td>

<td width="128" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">
<img src="http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/images/em-ft-tease-3.png" width="128" height="65"/>
</td>

<!-- SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS -->

<td width="53" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">
<img src="http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/images/em-ft-sm-fb.png" width="53" height="65"/>
</td>

<td width="60" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">
<img src="http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/images/em-ft-sm-yt.png" width="60" height="65"/>
</td>

<!-- UNSUBSCR. AND MANAGE -->
<td width="127" height="65">
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
<font face="Arial" size="1" color="#cfccd3">
Manage My Account
</font>
</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
<font face="Arial" size="1" color="#cfccd3">
Unsubscribe
</font>
</a>
</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Because you shouldn't be using a table for layout. Read some tutorials about CSS and layout.

Comment: your code in fiddle looks fine: [check out this]http://jsfiddle.net/QN9fU/

Comment: This is an email HTML. When Microsoft finally dies, we might see the day when tables die too, but that's fantasy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you put the footer also in a same table use a separate table like this

```
<table>
<!-- start email content-->
</table>
```

**separate the tables**

```
    <table>
    <tr align="left" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">

    <!-- TEASERS -->
    <td width="137" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">
    <img src="http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/images/em-ft-tease-1.png" width="137" height="65">
    </td>

    <td width="125" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">
    <img src="http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/images/em-ft-tease-2.png" width="125" height="65">
    </td>

    <td width="128" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">
    <img src="http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/images/em-ft-tease-3.png" width="128" height="65">
    </td>

    <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS -->

    <td width="53" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">
    <img src="http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/images/em-ft-sm-fb.png" width="53" height="65">
    </td>

    <td width="60" height="65" bgcolor="#322e39">
    <img src="http://www.webedgemarketing.info/dev/msa/images/em-ft-sm-yt.png" width="60" height="65">
    </td>

    <!-- UNSUBSCR. AND MANAGE -->
    <td width="127" height="65">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
    <font face="Arial" size="1" color="#cfccd3">
    Manage My Account
    </font>
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
    <font face="Arial" size="1" color="#cfccd3">
    Unsubscribe
    </font>
    </a>
    </td>

    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You sir/lady, are an absolute legend. That is completely illogical in terms of geometry, etc., but it works.